# Shrinking the boundary of a Riemann surface

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, teichmuller-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface with boundary. Let us shrink each connected component of the boundary into a point. We get a closed topological surface $Z$ with several marked points (which came from the components of the boundary of $X$) such that the complement $Z_0$ of these points carries a complex structure.

> Does there exist a complex structure on $Z$ such that it induces on $Z_0$ its original complex structure?

Rmk. I think that if such a complex structure exists, it is unique.

Comment: If there is, it would mean that there is homomorphic diffeomorphism $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{D}$ which is not the case.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Could you please add more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Complex structure on $X$ "knows" whether an end is a hole or a puncture.
The conformal invariant responsible for this is called the extremal length of the family of closed curves surrounding the hole/puncture.
See Ahlfors, Lectures on quasiconformal mappings.

The simplest case is a sphere with a puncture (conformally equivalent to the plane) vs sphere with a hole (conformally equivalent to a disk). These two things are conformally not equivalent. This is essentially Anton Petrunin's remark.